# How do I fit a landscape table to page width?

Tags: tables, width, horizontal

this is my latex, the columns always see to go over the page width. I know I set width using p instead of l. However, using p, the tables disappears to the next page where it is portrait mode.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{array}

    \afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
\textbf{Name(Store)}                                   & \textbf{Purpose}                  & \textbf{Support}                                                                       & \textbf{Medical References}                                                                                         \\ \hline
{\ul IBS (Google Play)}                       & Pain Assistance          & No                                                                            & Unknown. There is no direct (cited) scientific basis. Authors on the website do have a medical background. \\
{\ul FODMAP A toZ (Google Play, Apple Store)} & Diet                     & No, but contacting a qualified physician before adjusting the diet is advised & Unknown, created by patient.                                                                               \\
{\ul MySymptoms (Google Play, Apple Store)}   & Journal (Diet, Symptoms) & No, but contacting a qualified physician before adjusting the diet is advised & Unknown. However the included blogs do.                                                                    \\
{\ul Curing IBS (Google Play)}                & Informative              & No                                                                            & Unknown, created by patient.                                                                               \\
{\ul My IBS Diary (Google Play)}              & Journal (Diet, Symptoms) & Yes, cvs file can be exported and sent to physician                           & Unknown                                                                                                    \\
{\ul Irritable Bowel Syndrome (Google Play)}  & Informative              & No                                                                            & Unknown                                                                                                    \\
{\ul Zemedy}                                  & Therapy                  & Yes, expert can be contacted in the app                                       & Yes. (Latest) Medical references are listed                                                                \\
{\ul Monash University FODMAP diet}           & Journal (Diet)           & No                                                                            & Yes. Created at Monash University                                                                          \\
{\ul Bristol Stool Chart}                     & Journal                  & Yet, csv file can be exported and sent to physician                           & Yes, namely the Bristol Stool Chart.                                                                       \\
                                              &                          &                                                                               &                                                                                                           
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}
```

This is the result
[image]

Comment: Please mak e acomplete compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages. Regarding your issue: you might be interested in the `tabularx` package.

Comment: the last change the l to `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{...}` with ... chosen so the table is not too wide,

Comment: Apart from that, why do you use `captionof` in combination with a `table` and `landscape`?

Comment: @leandriis, not supposed to?

Comment: @leandriis , added the packages

Comment: Short version, use tabularx witn `\linewidth` and replace at least one of the `l` columns with an `X` column.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version using `tabularx` to allow the table to be as wide as the textwidth. I have also removed the `table` environment as it is not needed here:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}


    \afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}

%\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XlXX}
\hline
\textbf{Name(Store)}                                   & \textbf{Purpose}                  & \textbf{Support}                                                                       & \textbf{Medical References}                                                                                         \\ \hline
{\ul IBS  (Google Play)}                       & Pain Assistance          & No                                                                            & Unknown. There is no direct (cited) scientific basis. Authors on the website do have a medical background. \\
{\ul FODMAP A toZ  (Google Play, Apple Store)} & Diet                     & No, but contacting a qualified physician before adjusting the diet is advised & Unknown, created by patient.                                                                               \\
{\ul MySymptoms  (Google Play, Apple Store)}   & Journal (Diet, Symptoms) & No, but contacting a qualified physician before adjusting the diet is advised & Unknown. However the included blogs do.                                                                    \\
{\ul Curing IBS (Google Play)}                & Informative              & No                                                                            & Unknown, created by patient.                                                                               \\
{\ul My IBS Diary  (Google Play)}              & Journal (Diet, Symptoms) & Yes, cvs file can be exported and sent to physician                           & Unknown                                                                                                    \\
{\ul Irritable Bowel Syndrome (Google Play)}  & Informative              & No                                                                            & Unknown                                                                                                    \\
{\ul Zemedy}                                  & Therapy                  & Yes, expert can be contacted in the app                                       & Yes. (Latest) Medical references are listed                                                                \\
{\ul Monash University FODMAP diet}           & Journal (Diet)           & No                                                                            & Yes. Created at Monash University                                                                          \\
{\ul Bristol Stool Chart}                     & Journal                  & Yet, csv file can be exported and sent to physician                           & Yes, namely the Bristol Stool Chart.                                                                       \\
                                              &                          &                                                                               &                                                                                                           
\end{tabularx}

\captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here I have used the `sidewaystable` environment from the `rotating` package instead of the `landscape` approach:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}


\begin{document}



    \begin{sidewaystable}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XlXX}
\hline
\textbf{Name(Store)}                                   & \textbf{Purpose}                  & \textbf{Support}                                                                       & \textbf{Medical References}                                                                                         \\ \hline
{\ul IBS  (Google Play)}                       & Pain Assistance          & No                                                                            & Unknown. There is no direct (cited) scientific basis. Authors on the website do have a medical background. \\
{\ul FODMAP A toZ  (Google Play, Apple Store)} & Diet                     & No, but contacting a qualified physician before adjusting the diet is advised & Unknown, created by patient.                                                                               \\
{\ul MySymptoms  (Google Play, Apple Store)}   & Journal (Diet, Symptoms) & No, but contacting a qualified physician before adjusting the diet is advised & Unknown. However the included blogs do.                                                                    \\
{\ul Curing IBS (Google Play)}                & Informative              & No                                                                            & Unknown, created by patient.                                                                               \\
{\ul My IBS Diary  (Google Play)}              & Journal (Diet, Symptoms) & Yes, cvs file can be exported and sent to physician                           & Unknown                                                                                                    \\
{\ul Irritable Bowel Syndrome (Google Play)}  & Informative              & No                                                                            & Unknown                                                                                                    \\
{\ul Zemedy}                                  & Therapy                  & Yes, expert can be contacted in the app                                       & Yes. (Latest) Medical references are listed                                                                \\
{\ul Monash University FODMAP diet}           & Journal (Diet)           & No                                                                            & Yes. Created at Monash University                                                                          \\
{\ul Bristol Stool Chart}                     & Journal                  & Yet, csv file can be exported and sent to physician                           & Yes, namely the Bristol Stool Chart.                                                                       \\
                                              &                          &                                                                               &                                                                                                           
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Table caption}
    \end{sidewaystable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This last example contains some suggestions on how you could increase the readability of your table (I have removed the underline commands, added horizontal ruleds from the `booktabs` package as well as some more horizontal and vertical space between the columns and rows. Lastly, I have also used some abbreviations in order to save some space in the table)

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}


    \afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
\textbf{Name(Store)}                                   & \textbf{Purpose}                  & \textbf{Support}                                                                       & \textbf{Medical References}                                                                                         \\ \midrule
{ IBS  (GP)}                       & Pain Assistance          & No                                                                            & Unknown. There is no direct (cited) scientific basis. Authors on the website do have a medical background. \\
{ FODMAP A toZ  (GP, AS)} & Diet                     & No, but contacting a qualified physician before adjusting the diet is advised & Unknown, created by patient.                                                                               \\
{ MySymptoms  (GP, AS)}   & Journal (Diet, Symptoms) & No, but contacting a qualified physician before adjusting the diet is advised & Unknown. However the included blogs do.                                                                    \\
{ Curing IBS (GP)}                & Informative              & No                                                                            & Unknown, created by patient.                                                                               \\
{ My IBS Diary  (GP)}              & Journal (Diet, Symptoms) & Yes, cvs file can be exported and sent to physician                           & Unknown                                                                                                    \\
{ Irritable Bowel Syndrome (GP)}  & Informative              & No                                                                            & Unknown                                                                                                    \\
{ Zemedy}                                  & Therapy                  & Yes, expert can be contacted in the app                                       & Yes. (Latest) Medical references are listed                                                                \\
{ Monash University FODMAP diet}           & Journal (Diet)           & No                                                                            & Yes. Created at Monash University                                                                          \\
{ Bristol Stool Chart}                     & Journal                  & Yet, csv file can be exported and sent to physician                           & Yes, namely the Bristol Stool Chart.                                                                       \\
  \bottomrule
  \multicolumn{4}{p{\textwidth}}{Abbreviations: GP = Google Play, AS = Apple Store}
\end{tabularx}

\captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}


\end{document}
```

[image]